# Table column split by value to other columns and it's values

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have table this kind if look and it represent specifications for products

[image]

where 1st columns is SKU and serve as ID and 2nd column us specifications specifications title,Value and 0 or 1 as optional parameter(1 is default if it missed) separated by "~" and ech option is seperated by ^

I want to split it to table with SKU and each of specifications title as column header and value as it's value

I manage to write this code to split it to records with dived specifications and stack with separating title from value for each specification and record and how looking for help with this

```
    let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Таблица1"]}[Content],
    Type = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Part Number", type text}, {"Specifications", type text}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Type,"Specification##","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Specifications"}),
    SplitByDelimiter = (table, column, delimiter) => 
        let 
            Count = List.Count(List.Select(Text.ToList(Table.Column(table, column){0}), each _ = delimiter)) + 1, 
            Names = List.Transform(List.Numbers(1, Count), each column & "." & Text.From(_)), 
            Types = List.Transform(Names, each {_, type text}), 
            Split = Table.SplitColumn(table, column, Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(delimiter), Names), 
            Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Split, Types) 
        in 
            Typed, 
    Split = SplitByDelimiter(#"Replaced Value","Specifications","^"),
    Record = Table.ToRecords(Split)
in
    Record
```

Comment: There's some good answers [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918354/extract-mobile-numbers-to-other-cells-in-excel) about splitting a string in excel by a delimiter. The first VBA UDF in there may do what you need pretty easily and it's very lightweight.

Comment: Could you provide a sample table in code, please? Use Table.FromRecords or #table({},{{}})

Comment: Agreed with Sergey, please don't just post a screenshot of your input data. Also, can you post what your code returns today, and what you want output you want it to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I hope you still need this, as it took the whole evening. :))
Quite interesting task I must say!

I assume that **"~1"** is always combined with **"^"**, so **"~1^"** always ending field's value. I also assume that there is no **":"** in values, as all colons are removed.

IMO, you don't need to use Table.SplitColumn function at all.

```
let 
    //replace it with your Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Таблица1"]}[Content],
    Source = #table(type table [Part Number = Int64.Type, Specifications = text], {{104, "Model:~104~1^Type:~Watch~1^Metal Type~Steel~1"}, {105, "Model:~105~1^Type:~Watch~1^Metal Type~Titanium~1^Gem Type~Ruby~1"}}),

    //I don't know why do you replace these values, do you really need this?
    ReplacedValue = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"Specification##","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Specifications"}),
    TransformToLists = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {"Specifications", each List.Transform(List.Select(Text.Split(_ & "^", "~1^"), each _ <> "") , each Text.Split(Text.Replace(_, ":", ""), "~"))  } ),
    ConvertToTable = Table.TransformColumns(TransformToLists, {"Specifications", each Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.FromColumns(_))}),
    ExpandedSpecs = Table.TransformRows(ConvertToTable, (x) => Table.ExpandTableColumn(Table.FromRecords({x}), "Specifications", Table.ColumnNames(x[Specifications])) ),
    UnionTables = Table.Combine(ExpandedSpecs),
    Output = UnionTables
in
    Output
```

**UPDATE:**

How it works (skipping obvious steps):

***TransformToLists***: TransformColumns takes table, and a list of column names and functions applied to *this* column's value. So *it applies several nested functions to the value of "Specifications" field of each row*. These functions do the following: List.Select returns list of non-empty values, which in order was obtained by applying Text.Split function to the value of "Specifications" field having "**:**"s removed:

```
   Text.Split(
              Text.Replace(_, ":", "")
              , "~")
```

Each keyword means that following function applied to every processed value (it can be field, column, row/record, list item, text, function, etc), which is indicated with the underscore sign. This underscore can be replaced with a function:

```
  each _ equals (x) => some_function_that_returns_corresponding_value(x)
```

So,

```
  each Text.Replace(_, ":", "") 
      equals 
  (x) => Text.Replace(x, ":", "") //where x is any variable name. 

  //You can go further and make it typed, although generally it is not needed:
  (x as text) => Text.Replace(x, ":", "") 

  //You can also write a custom function and use it:
  (x as text) => CustomFunctionName(x)
```

Having said, *TransformToLists* step returns a table with two columns: "Part number" and "Specifications", containing list of lists. Each of these lists has two values: column name and its value. This happens because initial value in "Specifications" field has to be split twice: first it is split to pairs by "~1^", and then each pair is split by "~". So now we have column name and its value in each nested list, and now we have to convert them all into a single table.

***ConvertToTable***: We apply TransformColumns again, using a function for each row's "Specifications" field (remember, a list of lists). We use Table.FromColumns, as it takes a list of lists as an argument, and it returns a table where 1st row is column headers and second is their values. Then we promote 1st row to headers. Now we have a table, and "Specifications" field containing nested table with variable number of columns. And we have to put them all together.

***ExpandedSpecs***: Table.TransformRows applies transformation function to every row (as a record) in a table (in the code it is signed as *x*). You can write your custom function, as I did:

```
= Table.ExpandTableColumn( //this function expands nested table. It needs a table, but "x" that we have is a record. So we do the conversion:
    Table.FromRecords({x}) //function takes a list of records, so {x} means a list with single value of x
    , "Specifications" //Column to expand
    , Table.ColumnNames(x[Specifications]) //3rd argument is a list of resulting columns. It takes table as an argument, and table is contained within "Specifications" field.
 )
```

It returns a list of tables (having single row each), and we combine them using Table.Combine at ***UnionTables*** step. This results in a table having all the columns from combined tables, with nulls when there is no such a column in some of them.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Look`s it's work. It throw an error about duplicated column "Part number",but I fixed it. The **"~1"** not always in specifications, but yeah,it's always before **"^"**. Could you explain few thing - using "each",underline char "_" and this contraction "(x) => Table.ExpandTableColumn"

Comment: I've edited the answer and added detailed explanation.

Comment: Thx. Now have a chance to understood syntax of this each command

Answer (score 0):

A `TextToColumns` VBA solution is much simpler if I understand what you are asking [MSDN for `Range.TextToColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx)

Comment: it's usual split and this just like "SplitTextByDelimiter" in Power query and don't give the opportunity to split Spec-Title from Value and keep reference to part number. And i want it to split to (for example - 1st row of table i send) "Part number","Model" and then row with part number and value of Model specification if it's presented it cell